# Htaccess without "directory" doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^u/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ home.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

I basically want to remove `u` but when I do it nothing happens.
I want to display `site.com/home.php?u=$1` as `site.com/$1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change your rewrite rule to below and it will work. And also you have not included RewriteEngine On.

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)u=\$1($|&)
RewriteRule ^home\.php$ /$1?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: Also I have a problem with every links like if I have js file and inside js file I have like ajax request to some file url nothing works and it is little hard to change every single file with / before every link. Is there some option in htaccess for that?